# Min problem on integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, integer-sequences, global-optimization

Let $n$ be any integer greater than $2^{10^6}$. Given any $s\le (\log_2 n)/1000$ integers $1=q_1\le q_2\le \cdots q_{s-1}\le q_s=n$. Prove that
$$\min_\ell\left(\sum_{i=1}^\ell q_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=\ell+1}^s\frac{1}{q_i}\right)\le \frac{1}{64}$$

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Hint:  show that for at least one choice of $\ell$, $\sum_{i=1}^\ell q_i$ is not much larger than $q_\ell$, $\sum_{i=\ell+1}^s 1/q_i$ is not much larger than $1/q_{\ell+1}$, and $q_{\ell+1}$ is much larger than $q_\ell$.

Comment: (The intuition here is that the $q_i$ are “lacunary on average”, since it needs to increase from $1$ to $n$ in much fewer than $\log n$ steps. This can be formalized using the pigeonhole principle or Markov’s inequality.)

Comment: @TerryTao I used your hint as inspiration, and in the end I got a rather clean treatment without the pigeonhole principle or Markov’s inequality.

Comment: Nice question. I do not understand the downvote and the "close" suggestion.

Comment: @GHf, maybe someone mistook it for an exercise from an intro Number Theory textbook. May someone was annoyed at the lack of motivation, the weird unexplained constants $2^{10^6}$ and $1000$. Maybe someone's finger slipped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us denote
$$\sigma_\ell:=\sum_{i=1}^\ell q_i\qquad\text{and}\qquad\tau_\ell:=\sum_{i=\ell+1}^s\frac{1}{q_i}.$$
Then
$$\prod_{\ell=1}^{s-1}\left(\frac{q_\ell}{q_{\ell+1}}\cdot\frac{\sigma_{\ell+1}}{\sigma_\ell}\cdot\frac{\tau_{\ell-1}}{\tau_\ell}\right)=\frac{q_1}{q_s}\cdot\frac{\sigma_{s}}{\sigma_1}\cdot\frac{\tau_0}{\tau_{s-1}}=\sigma_s\tau_0>n,$$
hence there exists $\ell\in\{1,2,\dotsc,s-1\}$ such that
$$\frac{q_\ell}{q_{\ell+1}}\cdot\frac{\sigma_{\ell+1}}{\sigma_\ell}\cdot\frac{\tau_{\ell-1}}{\tau_\ell}>n^{1/(s-1)}>n^{1/s}=2^{1000}.$$
On the other hand, the left-hand side equals
$$\frac{q_\ell}{q_{\ell+1}}\left(1+\frac{q_{\ell+1}}{\sigma_\ell}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{q_\ell\tau_\ell}\right)
=\frac{q_\ell}{q_{\ell+1}}+\frac{q_\ell}{\sigma_\ell}+\frac{1}{q_{\ell+1}\tau_\ell}+\frac{1}{\sigma_\ell\tau_\ell},$$
so for the same $\ell$ we have
$$\frac{q_\ell}{q_{\ell+1}}+\frac{q_\ell}{\sigma_\ell}+\frac{1}{q_{\ell+1}\tau_\ell}+\frac{1}{\sigma_\ell\tau_\ell}>2^{1000}.$$
The first three terms on the left-hand side do not exceed $1$, hence in fact
$$\sigma_\ell\tau_\ell<\frac{1}{2^{1000}-3}.$$

Comment: This putting things together is just amazing!

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you, this comment means a lot to me. I also follow your posts, and I am a fan. Respect.

Comment: Nice answer!  I still think the more pedestrian approach I sketched may be more pedagogically instructive than this slick proof, but perhaps the OP may wish to reconstruct that argument by himself/herself, and your argument does contain some nice additional tricks that could be useful in other problems.   (Also, I would say that you are still using a version of the pigeonhole principle in this argument in order to locate the good index $\ell$.)

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks! Yes, choosing $\ell$ is a kind of analytic pigeonhole principle, although I think it was formalized earlier: the average (in this case geometric mean) is upper bounded by the maximum!